# How are VHDs in Azure Storage charged?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

If I create and attach a 200GB VHD to my Azure Virtual Machine and only consume 15GB of this drive, am I charged for the  full 200GB or the 15GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VHD's are persisted as page blobs and so you are charged for the space consumed in the blob.

From this:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#storage

> For Windows Azure Drive storage, you will be billed only for the storage space used by the page blob and the read/write transactions to the page blob. You will not be charged for read transactions that utilize the local drive cache. Windows Azure Drive usage is billed at the same rates as standard Windows Azure Storage and is included with Windows Azure Storage usage in your bill. There is not a separate line item for Windows Azure Drive on your bill.

Comment: @Rick i read this on the Azure site too but still had doubts. so in effect you are saying i would be charged for the 15GB in my scenario?

Comment: @PaulBrown - this is correct. You pay for the storage you consume. In the example given in the original question: It would be the cost of storing 15GB.

Comment: Note that this answer is specific to Standard discs. Premium discs have different rules; as specified [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/):

> If the empty 100 GB disk is backed by a Premium Storage Account, then you will be charged for a P0 (128 GB) disk. If any other type of Storage Account is used, then you’ll only be billed for the storage space used to store the data that is written to the disk regardless of the allocated disk size.

I think that means pricing on SSD disks are dependent on the size of the provision but I haven yet to confirm that.